# How do you programatically determine who submitted a webform?

Tags: webforms

When I add a value element to a new webform draft and I attempt to prepopulate the element with a token listed as available, the element does not get populated.

Comment: You need to provide more detail, like the element and how you're currently trying to prepopulate it.

Comment: Thanks for your response @beltouche  I am trying to populate a new webform, with one element.  The YAML source is: `user_name01:
  '#type': value
  '#title': 'User Name'
  '#value': '[current-user:display-name]'
flexbox:
  '#type': flexbox`

Comment: Drupal core version is 8.8.3, webform, related webform modules, views and webform_views are installed.  All modules are up to date.

Answer (score 0):

@beltouche: It should be noted that this YAML source creates a webform that internally stores the displayname property.  As a result the identified user is stored wherever the webform submissions are stored.  I now assume this is as designed.  It seems to me that the prepopulation of a webform using something like `{{ user.displayname }}` is best accomplished by using a block/webform hybrid content type.  Am I on the right track with this thinking?

Comment: Please do not post updates to your question as an answer, use the "Edit" link below the original question instead. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Hudri Even if the "Edit" link is disabled after 5 minutes and an additional comment is believed needed to avoid possible confusion? I'm new to this forum, so your patience is appreciated.